# Bootstrap 5 carousel with multiple sliders

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

i'm trying to make bootstrap 5 carousel with multi items. but in my code i could display 3 items at a time. how can make 6 items at a time. I try to change the value in JS code  but there it doesn't work. Please correct my following so it could display 6 items at a time and can be vary later. here is complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style type="text/css">
  body{
    background: #f7f7;
  }
   @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div {
        display: none;
    }
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div:first-child {
        display: block;
    }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    display: flex;
}

/* medium and up screens */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end.active,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
      transform: translateX(25%);
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start.active, 
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
      transform: translateX(-25%);
    }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-end,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-start { 
  transform: translateX(0);
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid text-center my-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row mx-auto my-auto justify-content-center">
        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 1</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="img/2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 2</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="img/3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 3</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="img/4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 4</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="img/4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 4</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')

items.forEach((el) => {
    const minPerSlide = 3
    let next = el.nextElementSibling
    for (var i=1; i<minPerSlide; i++) {
        if (!next) {
            // wrap carousel by using first child
            next = items[0]
        }
        let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
        el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
        next = next.nextElementSibling
    }
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your bootstrap columns from col-md-4 to col-md-2 so that they can appear 6 columns per row and on your javascript code change minPerSlide to 6
Here is the code for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style type="text/css">
  body{
    background: #f7f7;
  }
   @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div {
        display: none;
    }
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div:first-child {
        display: block;
    }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    display: flex;
}

/* medium and up screens */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end.active,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
      transform: translateX(25%);
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start.active, 
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
      transform: translateX(-25%);
    }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-end,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-start { 
  transform: translateX(0);
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid text-center my-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row mx-auto my-auto justify-content-center">
        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 1</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="img/2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 2</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="img/3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 3</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="img/4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 4</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="img/4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 4</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')

items.forEach((el) => {
    const minPerSlide = 6
    let next = el.nextElementSibling
    for (var i=1; i<minPerSlide; i++) {
        if (!next) {
            // wrap carousel by using first child
            next = items[0]
        }
        let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
        el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
        next = next.nextElementSibling
    }
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```